# insertImage JS auto prepend file location

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to prepend a drill down to my file without the user being able to touch that in the prompt text field as I currently have it set like this:

```
function iimages() {
    var img = prompt ("Enter the image link", "../../../../uploads/");
    if (img != null) {
    editor.document.execCommand("insertImage", false, img);
    }
}
```

so where I have the `../../../../uploads/` Add that in automatically so the user is unable to change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this way:

```
function iimages() {
    var img = prompt ("Enter the image link", "example.jpg");
    if (img != null) {
      editor.document.execCommand("insertImage", false, "../../../../uploads/" + img);
    }
}
```

Comment: @phpcoder If it helped you you can mark it as an accepted answer, it would help me back. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Sure I am just waiting for it to let me :D